# How to create a vector of class objects in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I am trying to create a simple stack using vector in C++.

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>

class Site
{
    public:
        int i; // site position i (x-axis)
        int s; // site state
        vector<Site> neighbors;
        Site(void);
        Site(int ii, int ss);
        void AddNeighbor(Site &site);
};
Site::Site()
{
    i = -1;
    s = -1;
    vector<Site> neighbors;
}
Site::Site(int ii, int ss) 
{
    i = ii;
    s = ss;
}
void Site::AddNeighbor(Site &site)
{
    neighbors.push_back(site);
}

void testStack()
{
    int tot = 600;
    vector<Site> myStack();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < tot)
    {
        Site site(i, 1);
        myStack.push_back(site);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < tot)
    {
        Site *site = myStack.back();
        myStack.pop_back();
        cout << site->i << site->s << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Compiler errors:

> ising_wolff.cpp: In function ‘void testStack()’:
>   ising_wolff.cpp:373:17: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in
>   ‘myStack’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector()’
>            myStack.push_back(site);
>                    ^ ising_wolff.cpp:380:30: error: request for member ‘back’ in ‘myStack’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector()’
>            Site *site = myStack.back();
>                                 ^ ising_wolff.cpp:381:17: error: request for member ‘pop_back’ in ‘myStack’, which is of non-class type
>   ‘std::vector()’
>            myStack.pop_back();

What do these errors mean?

Here are some sites I have looked at:

1) [Creating objects while adding them into vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802006/create-objects-while-adding-them-into-vector)

2) [push_back causing errors in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166321/push-back-causeing-an-error-when-using-vectors-in-c)

3) [how to create vectors of class object](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/7950/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
vector<Site> myStack();
```

This is actually a function declaration. The function is called `myStack` and it returns a `vector<Site>`. What you actually want is:

```
vector<Site> myStack;
```

The type of `neighbours` at the moment will store copies of the objects, not references. If you really want to store references, I recommend using a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) (rather than using pointers):

```
vector<reference_wrapper<Site>> neighbors;
```

Comment: If I declare neighbors as you said, the method `AddNeighbors` in class `Site` will remain correct? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: when I use `std::reference_wrapper`, like you proposed, compiler gives me the error: `In member function ‘void Site::AddNeighbor(Site&)’: ising_wolff.cpp:38:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Site> >::push_back(Site&)’` in `neighbors.push_back(site);`. And then prints a lot of "candidates" to replace it... The list is long that it is impossible to read

Comment: @Girardi Oh sorry, I misunderstood your previous question. You need to do `neighbors.push_back(std::ref(site))`.

Comment: it says that `ref` is not a member of `std`

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't notice the `header` in the link you referenced =)

Answer (score 27):

### How to create a vector of class objects in C++?

Start with something simpler so you can get the hang of it.

**First, create a vector of primitive ints:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  vector<int> sites(5);
  sites.push_back(5);
  for(int x = 0; x < sites.size(); x++){
    cout << sites[x];
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

Running it:

```
./test
000005
```

**Create a vector of class objects in a similar way as above:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Site {
public:
    int i;
};

int main() {
    vector<Site> listofsites;
    Site *s1 = new Site;
    s1->i = 7;
    Site *s2 = new Site;
    s2->i = 9;
    listofsites.push_back(*s1);
    listofsites.push_back(*s2);
    vector<Site>::iterator it;
    for (it = listofsites.begin(); it != listofsites.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which should print:

```
79
```

Answer (score 7):

```
vector<Site> myStack();
```

This is wrong. Lose the `()`.

You're declaring a function, not a vector.

Just write:

```
vector<Site> myStack;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
vector<Site> myStack;
myStack.resize(100); //will create 100 <Site> objects
```